# lookup function in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any built in function to enable the lookup function in PHP like the excel one? I thought the array_search would be the closest one, but it won't work if the mixed needle(value) has more than one values. To illustrate, the lookup I try to perform is:

```
function lookup($datatype){
    $array = array(
        'BINARY' => 'RAW',
        'REAL' => 'FLOAT',
        'INTEGER' => 'NUMBER',
        'DATETIME' => 'DATE', 
        'VARCHAR' => 'VARCHAR2',
        'DATETIME' => 'TIMESTAMP',
        'VARBINARY' => 'BFILE',
        'INT' => 'NUMERIC'
        );

    $key = array_search($datatype, $array);

    return $key;
}
```

If the lookup is for the 'RAW', array_search will return 'BINARY', but when the lookup is 'DATE', it won't return anything.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't have the same key twice in your array! `'DATETIME' => 'DATE',` does NOT exist in your array.

Answer (score 1):

the $array has the same key 'DATETIME' twice ,second one will overrite the first, so $array don't have the 'DATE'  key

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same key twice in your array! You can instead of 'DATETIME' to 'DATETIME_test'

```
function lookup($datatype){
        $array = array(
                'BINARY' => 'RAW',
                'REAL' => 'FLOAT',
                'INTEGER' => 'NUMBER',
                'DATETIME_test' => 'DATE',
                'VARCHAR' => 'VARCHAR2',
                'DATETIME' => 'TIMESTAMP',
                'VARBINARY' => 'BFILE',
                'INT' => 'NUMERIC',
        );

        $key = array_search($datatype, $array);

        return $key;
    }

    var_dump(lookup('DATE'));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned your array, there is duplicate key of "DATETIME", so it will overwrite by last value. and your array would be as follow.

```
    $array = array(
        'BINARY' => 'RAW',
        'REAL' => 'FLOAT',
        'INTEGER' => 'NUMBER',
        'VARCHAR' => 'VARCHAR2',
        'DATETIME' => 'TIMESTAMP',
        'VARBINARY' => 'BFILE',
        'INT' => 'NUMERIC'
        );
so whenever you are trying to filter out or willing to get, only one key is available.
```

Better to write down with different key. and then try to array_search for key.